# Why doesn't the pointer for the char *str change when we reverse the string in this function?

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple function to perform in place reversal:

```
void in_place_reverse(char *str){
    if(!str || !(*str)){
        return;
    }

    char *str_end = str+strlen(str)-1;

    int temp;
    while(str < str_end){
        temp = *str;
        *(str++) = *str_end;
        *(str_end--) = temp;
    }
}
```

I'm just wondering why when I do something like this:

```
char str[] = "Reverse me!";
cout << "Original: " << str << endl;
in_place_reverse(str);
cout << "Reversed: " << str << endl;
```

`str` wasn't changed inside of the function. The reason I ask is because the line `*(str++)` is incrementing the pointer that points to `str`. So what I'm really asking is why something like this isn't necessary:

```
char *str_beg = str;
char *str_end = str+strlen(str)-1;

int temp;
while(str_beg < str_end){
    temp = *str_beg;
    *(str_beg++) = *str_end;
    *(str_end--) = temp;
}
```

So that we're not actually changing the pointer that points to the first position of `str`.

Comment: Why should the pointer change, the values are changed _in place_ as the function name says, there's just values swapped around.

Comment: Pointers, like any other variables, are passed by value, unless you pass them by reference like `char* &str`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually are doing this implicitely because 'str' is passed by value (read: 'as a copy in a temporary variable').

To clarify this without the (distracting) pointer: consider

```
void increment(int x) {
  x++;
}

int i = 1;
cout << i << endl;
increment(i);
cout << i << endl;
```

This will print '1' twice. The `x` that is seen *inside* the `increment` routine has the same *value* like the passed `i`. But it is not the *same* variable `i`. In fact it is a *copy of* `i`. When we return from the routine, the copy is discarded. Further reading: This would be different if we'd pass `x` *by reference*, like so:

```
void increment(int &x) {
  x++;
}
```

Comment: But this scenario is slightly different, because even though the function receives a pass-by-value variable of the pointer, the content of str actually does change outside of the function (i.e. it is reversed).

Comment: That's correct. You have to distinguish between *a pointer* that points to a string of characters and the string of characters itself. You could as well have used the passed `x` parameter in my example to index some global array. Then you would modify that global array (its content would change outside the function, as you describe) although the index `x` itself was discarded.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of the function `void in_place_reverse(char *str)` results in a copy of the pointer being created when the function is called, in a variable called `str` that is private and local to the in_place_reverse.  You can modify this value all you like without affecting the original that exists in the scope of the calling function.

Comment: So there is a copy of the pointer, but the values that it points to are not copied? Is that why str is actually reversed outside of the function?

Comment: Correct.  There is only one copy of the data, but several pointers to it, depending on which code is running.  that is why the string is reversed in place.